# Como validar valor que vem por json do php para o ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

No php eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
            $invalido = (object) array(
                'invalido' => true
            );
            echo json_encode($invalido);
```

e preciso exibir no `success` do `ajax` perguntado se o `invalido` é `true`.
Tentei o seguinte:

```
success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);

           if(data.invalido == true)
           {
               alert('invalido');
           }

        }
```

Não está entrando no if, e no alert de cima está exibindo o seguinte:

```
{"invalido":true}{"scalar":false}
```

Como valido o que está vindo no `invalido`?

Eu preciso acessar o que está vindo neste `json`, acessar o `invalido`:

```
{"invalido":true}{"scalar":false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente

```js
var data = [{
  "invalido": true
}, {
  "scalar": false
}];

if (data[0].invalido == true) {
  console.log('invalido');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ou

```js
var data = [{
  "invalido": true
}, {
  "scalar": false
}];


$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  if (value.invalido == true)
    console.log("invalido");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu já estou recebendo um json e preciso somente validar o `invalido` desse json.

Comment: @SM_S coloquei duas formas de como você pode acessar o valor da chave invalido e fazer suas devidas validações.

Comment: Está mostrando este erro pela segunda forma: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"invalido":true}{"scalar":false}`

Comment: Mais alguma sugestão?